# Splitting an line of text?

Tags: php

I have things saved in a database such as:

```
Apple Banana Orange Pear
```

They are all saved in the database on one line, separated by spaces.

I want to retrieve this information from the database, and put them into html like so:

```
<li>Apple</li>
<li class="alt">Banana</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li class="alt">Pear</li>
```

How would I go about doing this? I've looked into explode() and then foreach, is that the best way?

```
$fruits = explode(" ", $q['fruits']);

$i = 1;

foreach( $fruits as $fruit ){

    if ($i % 2 == 0){
        $alt = ' class="alt"';
    }else{
        $alt = '';
    }

    echo "<li" . $alt . ">" . $value . "</li>";

$i++;
}
```

Comment: You've answered your own question, doesn't that code you provided work?

Comment: It does, I just updated it after posting - was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You may have to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$q['fruits']` contains string `"Apple Banana Orange Pear"` then...

**Code:**

```
$fruits = explode(" ", $q['fruits']);
$s = true;
foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
  if ($s) echo "<li>$fruit</li>\n";
  else echo "<li class=\"alt\">$fruit</li>\n";
  $s = !$s; 
  }
```

**Output:**

```
<li>Apple</li>
<li class="alt">Banana</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li class="alt">Pear</li>
```

Comment: Thank you - I have edited my post with what I've come up with, it works the exact same, is this still a good way?

Comment: Sure, it is... Don't use `$key => $value` if you don't need `$key` (numeric in this specific case). I've used `$fruit` instead, or just `$value` according to your code sample. Cheers